# Using Haneke to cache then play MP4 files with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, haneke

I'm looking for some help solving what seems like a simple problem, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I'm using Haneke from Cocoapods to cache MP4 files from URL (on my server) and then play the cached version using AVPlayer. I'm setting up an AVPreviewLayer inside a UICOllectionViewCell and running this code. The issue is that the player won't play the video initially, but it will play it again in the future (after i scroll back to that cell in the uicollectionview)

```
           let getUrl = NSURL(string: location)

            cache.fetch(URL: getUrl!).onSuccess { (data) in

                // Hacky way of getting cache URL from Haneke
                let basePath = DiskCache.basePath().stringByAppendingPathComponent("shared-data/original/")
                let path = DiskCache(path: basePath, capacity: UINT64_MAX).pathForKey(getUrl!.absoluteString)
                let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

                self.player = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)

                let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)

                playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds

                cell.videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

                print("Playing video")

                self.player.play()

            }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?